# Problemas con obtener localizacion en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas tardes amigos tengo un problema,
bueno he estado haciendo pruebas y pues me gustaria saber donde estoy fallando , segun veo cuando hago debugeo, location me devuelve null y por ende no me puede devolver el getAltitud o alguna otra propidad , me gustaria saber el error o si no es eso de location que puede ser? si tengo los permisos en manifest y puej tengo un emulador nexus 5x api21 android 5.0.2

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.btnSitios_Turisticos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sitios_turistico);

    this.btnSitios_Turisticos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intento_abrir_mapsactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity1.class);
            startActivity(intento_abrir_mapsactivity);

        }
    });




    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

           return;
        }
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Toast.makeText(this
                ,"La latitud es:"+String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }





}
```

aqui he estao haciendo una prueba pero location es null cuando hago el debugeo muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: El problema es que usas getLastKnownLocation() , si no has obtenido un valor   anteriormente no tendrás un valor proporcionado como geolocalización. Es importante comentar que generalmente se usa además del  GPS_PROVIDER el proveedor NETWORK_PROVIDER para asegurar obtener geolocalización en 4G o WiFi, agrego respuesta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la ubicacion tienes que hacer lo siguiente

primero en el build gradle importamos la libreria de location de play services

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

Vamos a usar el FuseLocationProviderClient, para eso lo declaramos

```
 private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
```

Luego en `onCreate()` lo inicializamos

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

Listo, ahora lo unico que nos queda es pedir la ubicacion, para eso vamos a necesitar

1. Pedir permisos
2. Obtener la ubicacion

Vamos a crear un metodo donde primero pida los permisos y luego obtenga la ubicacion

```
    private void solicitarUbicacion(){
private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS ;            
//Permisos para FINE LOCATION
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);




                    return;
                }
                //Obteniendo la ubicacion
                mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                                //Sabiendo que obtuvimos location, lo usamos
                                if (location != null) {
                                    Log.e("Latitud: ", +location.getLatitude() + "Longitud: " + location.getLongitude());


                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Este metodo lo podes llamar adentro del `onCreate()`

```
solicitarUbicacion();
```

Con eso te deberia funcionar, no te olvides de agregar tus permisos al manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Cualquier duda que tengas hice un video hace un mes , lo dejo en [ESTE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHIgI70bvx8&t) link

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, por si acaso no sabes como se haria para para ese evento addOnSuccessListener? osea quiero solo que me capture 1 vez ese evento despues ya no como podria?.

Comment: addOnSuccessListener se va a lanzar solo una vez cuando obtenga las coordenadas de location, no esta constantemente actualizando a no ser que lo vuelvas a llamar

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente debes definir los permisos necesarios en tu AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Ya definiste la petición de estos permisos para dispositivos con Android 6.0 o posterior por lo tanto se debe visualizar esta pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

algo importante, tu servicio de Localización debe estar activado de otra forma `location` tendrá un valor null

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Los 3 puntos anteriores son necesarios para obtener geolocalización, pero es importante saber que el proveedor que usas puede no obtener los datos (usas únicamente `NETWORK_PROVIDER`), así que generalmente se usan los proveedores `GPS_PROVIDER` o `NETWORK_PROVIDER`, ya que puede ser que te encuentres en una red 4G o en una red WiFi y con esto aseguramos obtener la posición.

Este sería el código:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            return;
        }
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = null;
        LocationListener mlocListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            //Existe GPS_PROVIDER obtiene ubicación
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }

        if(location == null){ //Trata con NETWORK_PROVIDER
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                //Existe NETWORK_PROVIDER obtiene ubicación
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
        }
        if(location != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "La latitud es:" + location.getLatitude() + " la longitud es: " +location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo obtener geolocalización", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
        }

    }
```

De esta forma podrás obtener de una forma adecuada tu geolocalización.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]